# O 'window' é renderizado pelo dom ou vem antes disso?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

**Uma curiosidade:** Gostaria de saber se a janela é renderizada pelo `dom` ao carregar a janela, pois o documento, geralmente é `window.document.html`. Ou o `dom` vem depois desse parâmetro?

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você quer dizer com "renderizado pelo DOM". Mas a resposta do MarvinMedeiros te esclarece? Ou é outra coisa que você quer saber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o DOM é parte do objeto window, logo o objeto window precisa vir antes para renderizá-lo. Veja na documentação da [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) aonde se diz o seguinte:

> **Tip:** The document is a part of the Window object and can be accessed as window.document.

Significa que assim que o HTML é carregado, ele se torna o Objeto DOM. Logo window não é "renderizado" pelo document e sim ao contrário.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação!